# Button size issue using Tkinter() : python

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I'm having issues with some buttons being larger than others in the following Tkinter form? 
Please see code as to how ive formatted buttons,  & attatched image: [my Form][1]

```py
from tkinter import *
def raise_frame(frame):
    frame.tkraise()
window = Tk()
window.title('Title')
window.configure(background = 'black')
#home page
Home = Frame(window)
Home.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky = 'news')
Label(Home, text = "Category",fg='light green',bg = 'black',font = 'none 12 bold').grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan = 5,sticky = 'nesw')

#A-Z buttons
_fg = 'light green'
_font = 'none 12 bold'
_sticky = 'news'

Button(window, text = 'A',bg = _fg,font = _font) .grid(row=1,column=0, columnspan = 1, sticky = _sticky)
Button(window, text = 'B',bg = _fg,font = _font) .grid(row=1,column=1, columnspan = 1, sticky = _sticky)
Button(window, text = 'C',bg = _fg,font = _font) .grid(row=1,column=2, columnspan = 1, sticky = _sticky)
Button(window, text = 'D',bg = _fg,font = _font) .grid(row=1,column=3, columnspan = 1, sticky = _sticky)
Button(window, text = 'E',bg = _fg,font = _font) .grid(row=1,column=4, columnspan = 1, sticky = _sticky)
Button(window, text = 'F',bg = _fg,font = _font) .grid(row=1,column=5, columnspan = 1, sticky = _sticky)

Button(window, text = 'G',bg = _fg,font = _font) .grid(row=2,column=0, columnspan = 1, sticky = _sticky)
Button(window, text = 'H',bg = _fg,font = _font) .grid(row=2,column=1, columnspan = 1, sticky = _sticky)
Button(window, text = 'I',bg = _fg,font = _font) .grid(row=2,column=2, columnspan = 1, sticky = _sticky)
Button(window, text = 'J',bg = _fg,font = _font) .grid(row=2,column=3, columnspan = 1, sticky = _sticky)
Button(window, text = 'K',bg = _fg,font = _font) .grid(row=2,column=4, columnspan = 1, sticky = _sticky)
Button(window, text = 'L',bg = _fg,font = _font) .grid(row=2,column=5, columnspan = 1, sticky = _sticky)

raise_frame(Home)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: delete columnspan? let me know the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your first column is bigger is because you most probably added a category label on position `row =0, col = 0`. This makes all button in first column use the size of `category` word. (This is not shown in you sample code but in the image).
What you need to do is change the `columnspan` of category to use all of the columns available ( eg `columnspan = 6`). This way the A,G,M,S,Y button will only be as wide as they need to be. Please try and post you complete code/ snapshot of image

category and button must all be added to the same parent frame for this to work

Fixed code:

```
from tkinter import *
def raise_frame(frame):
    frame.tkraise()
window = Tk()
window.title('Title')
window.configure(background = 'black')
#home page
Home = Frame(window)
Home.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky = 'news')

l = Label(Home, text = "Category",fg='light green',bg = 'black',font = 'none 12 bold')
l.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan = 6,sticky = 'nesw')

#A-Z buttons
_fg = 'light green'
_font = 'none 12 bold'
_sticky = 'news'

Button(Home, text = 'A',bg = _fg,font = _font) .grid(row=1,column=0, columnspan = 1, sticky = _sticky)
Button(Home, text = 'A',bg = _fg,font = _font) .grid(row=1,column=0, columnspan = 1, sticky = _sticky)
Button(Home, text = 'A',bg = _fg,font = _font) .grid(row=1,column=0, columnspan = 1, sticky = _sticky)
Button(Home, text = 'B',bg = _fg,font = _font) .grid(row=1,column=1, columnspan = 1, sticky = _sticky)
Button(Home, text = 'C',bg = _fg,font = _font) .grid(row=1,column=2, columnspan = 1, sticky = _sticky)
Button(Home, text = 'D',bg = _fg,font = _font) .grid(row=1,column=3, columnspan = 1, sticky = _sticky)
Button(Home, text = 'E',bg = _fg,font = _font) .grid(row=1,column=4, columnspan = 1, sticky = _sticky)
Button(Home, text = 'F',bg = _fg,font = _font) .grid(row=1,column=5, columnspan = 1, sticky = _sticky)

Button(Home, text = 'G',bg = _fg,font = _font) .grid(row=2,column=0, columnspan = 1, sticky = _sticky)
Button(Home, text = 'H',bg = _fg,font = _font) .grid(row=2,column=1, columnspan = 1, sticky = _sticky)
Button(Home, text = 'I',bg = _fg,font = _font) .grid(row=2,column=2, columnspan = 1, sticky = _sticky)
Button(Home, text = 'J',bg = _fg,font = _font) .grid(row=2,column=3, columnspan = 1, sticky = _sticky)
Button(Home, text = 'K',bg = _fg,font = _font) .grid(row=2,column=4, columnspan = 1, sticky = _sticky)
Button(Home, text = 'L',bg = _fg,font = _font) .grid(row=2,column=5, columnspan = 1, sticky = _sticky)

raise_frame(Home)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have tried the columnspan in the label....code is too long to put in comments so I'll edit the question....thanks

Comment: Please post your complete code otherwise we cannot help. `columnspan = 1` for the button themselves is useless (this is the default value of columnspan)

Comment: You need to make all your buttons childs of `Home` frame not of `window`. Change Label  column span to 6 and it works. I updated my answer accordingly

Comment: Ah i can't believe I didn't spot this! Thank you so much